# Calculate the coordinate on a sphere

Tags: python, math

How do you calculate the coordinate on a sphere if you know the xy angle and the z angle?

To elaborate:

I have a sphere with a radius, let's say 50cm.
The centre of the sphere is `xyz 0,0,0`

Lets put the origin point on the surface of the sphere at `0,50,0`

If we move x 90 degrees the coordinate would be `-50, 0, 0`

If we move z 90 then the coordinate would be `0, 0, 50`

If we return to the surface origin `0,50,0` and move x: `4 degrees` y: `72 degrees` and z: `64.6 degrees` what is the coordinate?

Rather than just answering the question, how would python calculate it? What is the equation and how would it be coded in python?

EDIT:

Having followed the suggested solution, I've still not getting what I expect.

r     is the Radius
alpha is the horizontal angle from the X axis
polar is the vertical angle from the Z axis

```
from math import cos, sin
def location_on_sphere(radius, alpha, polar):
    x = radius * sin(polar) * cos(alpha)
    y = radius * sin(polar) * sin(alpha)
    z = radius * cos(polar)
    print(str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + ' ' + str(z))

location_on_sphere(radius=0.5, alpha=0, polar=0)
```

When I enter `location_on_sphere(radius=0.5, alpha=0, polar=0)` I get x=0, y=0, z=0.5 ok, that seems correct.

So the point is at the top of the sphere, not ideal but ok.

If I bring the point down the sphere so `z=-90` it gives me `-0.4469983318002789 -0.0 -0.22403680806458506` I was expecting something like `x:0, y:90, z:0` or `x:90, y:0, z:0` since the z angle should now be at the xy plane. Do I have the correct equation or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Forget python for a moment.  Do you know how to do this calculation with pencil and paper?

Comment: That's a math question not a programming question. https://math.stackexchange.com/. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769011/converting-3d-polar-coordinates-to-cartesian-coordinates

Comment: Your confusion likely has to do with giving angles in degrees. Python's trig functions expect radians. As for your equations, it depends what you want the angles to measure. Currently `polar` has 0 at the north pole and pi at the south pole. If you want zero at the equator, you need to swap `sin(polar)` with `cos(polar)` in each of the equations (then `pi/2` would be the north pole and `-pi/2` would be the south pole).